# Failed review audit, and I don't understand why

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, triage

I was reviewing [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/28286098) and after having understood (with some difficulty) what the question was about, I went for the comments section and proceeded to click *Show more comments*. Some user suggested (quite humorously by the way) that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65769822/write-a-function-linesa-that-determines-how-many-balls-will-be-destroyed) seemed very similar and had already received answers. I went on examining the said question, and indeed, it proved to ask for a solution to the same problem with quite a few answers, one of which had been accepted. I also think it was better phrased than the one I was reviewing.

So, naturally, I decided to flag the original question as a duplicate. Here is what I was answered back:

> STOP! Look and Listen.

> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. This question is clear and answerable. While there may be minor flaws, it should be approved.

> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

I found the question not that *clear and answerable*, but ok, I'm not a native speaker myself and this will help me in the future have a sense of what questions should be approved.

However, concerning the duplicate issue, wasn't I right flagging it?

Comment: Just another example of a runaway tag that's so rampant with answerers that they'll answer/upvote anything and everything, regardless of how poor, or if a dupe, or whatever. ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have reached my limits in English (or in my knowledge of SO), but I don't get what you are saying. What's the 'runaway tag'? Who's 'they' that will answer? Sorry again, I'm lost here!

Comment: Sorry, i mean, the tag is highly popular, and the competition for earning rep there is very rough with so many posting answers. This often leads to questions that ordinarily would have been dupe closed, or downvoted, etc, being answered and upvoted instead. The audit system automatically chooses well received questions and uses them as audits under the assumption that if so many people upvoted it, it must be a stellar question. It isn't always accurate.

Comment: Ha! Basically, you're saying the audit system is reputation biased. Makes sense as the other question has an accepted answer but no upvotes. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: not always positive though, it also can take negative questions to make audits as well, just in the opposite direction

Comment: I wouldn't be too worried about a single audit fail, just take it as an example of what to look out for to identify a particular review as an audit or a real review. Skipping is always a safe choice

Comment: Thanks, and now I understand how some other user claimed they had come across a review that was obviously an audit one... And yes, skipping when in doubt may be the main advice I remembered from triage guide post.

Comment: Note that in this audit post, the accepted answer is terrible for the efficiency point of view, O(N^2) in the worst cqse...