# How to accept another question as duplicate of one's own question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405073/failed-review-audit-and-i-dont-understand-why) I asked a few days ago was flagged as a duplicate against [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit). That's ok for me, but then I received a mail suggesting me to "accept" this was a duplicate:

> Select the suggestions that answer your question. Your question will be associated with these links so future visitors can easily find the answer. Your question will be marked as a duplicate and become visible to the public again.

The thing is I don't see how I'm supposed to do that.

I've stumbled on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) then [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930) showing an (implemented in 2015) UI with a "That solved my problem" button. Alas, seems it's not implemented this way any more...

Comment: It's already closed as a duplicate so there's nothing else for you to do.

Comment: OK, thanks for the explanation, however, the workflow is a bit misleading and the questions I found here about this maybe outdated...

Comment: It was closed by someone with a dupehammer. They can close it immediately, so no further action from you was necessary. I, for instance, can only flag. So if I had flagged your question it would have remained open and the button would have been shown to you, because you could have accepted the duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, it's not logical that you are sent that email when the question has been closed. It looks like the system sends the email when the first dupe close vote arrives, without taking the "dupe-hammer" into consideration.

Comment: Thank you all for guiding me through this arcane. Now things make sense!

Answer (score 23):

If you see something like the following message:

[image]That means your question ***is already deemed closed*** by the community. In your specific case, that was done [by a single community member holding a gold badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230865/increase-close-vote-weight-for-gold-tag-badge-holders) for one of the tags of your question.

On the other hand, if you see something like this:

[image]That means that your question ***is not closed yet***, but you can choose to close it as a duplicate if that link is indeed helpful to you, using the radio buttons and the <kbd>Submit</kbd> button.

---

Regarding that mail you got, it seems like you didn’t post it in full. You got this email indicating that ***the question is already closed***. The start of that email is:

> This question may be a duplicate. It is closed and not accepting answers.
>
> **Question:** `<your question>`
>
> **Feedback:** This may be a duplicate question. Community members have suggested similar questions that may solve the problem. Review these to see if the question is a duplicate.

And the following part containing the one you quoted:

> What should I do next?
>
> **Review similar questions.** Community members have suggested similar questions that may solve the problem. Do any of these answer your question?
>
> **Select the suggestions that answer your question.** Your question will be associated with these links so future visitors can easily find the answer. Your question will be marked as a duplicate and become visible to the public again.

This section is indeed confusing because the email notifies you that the question ***is already closed***. You already lost the option to choose, so the phrasing of that message might need to be changed.

I have opened a follow-up support/bug meta post - [Email notification about a question getting closed (as duplicate) is confusing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405190/email-notification-about-a-question-getting-closed-as-duplicate-is-confusing)

Comment: Since you have the full text of the email (I personally have all emails disabled), you might want to post the suggestion in your last paragraph as a separate question (either here or on Meta.SE if it's the same for other sites). This is a bug, IMO.

Comment: @41686 I agree. As evident by this very meta question, it is rather confusing, especially for new users. Will create a follow-up MSE post and update here

Comment: @41686d6564 Updated with link above. The mail gave me the feeling it's SO specific so posted here in the end