# Email notification about a question getting closed (as duplicate) is confusing

Tags: support, status-completed, duplicate-questions, closed-questions, email

Following [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405110/how-to-accept-another-question-as-duplicate-of-ones-own-question) question, I decided to post this one.

This is part of the email notification you'll get if a question of yours is closed (as a duplicate):

> **This question may be a duplicate**. It is closed and not accepting answers.
>
> **Question:** `<link to question>`
>
> **Feedback:** This may be a duplicate question. Community members have suggested similar questions that may solve the problem. Review these
> to see if the question is a duplicate.
>
> [...]
>
> **What should I do next?**
>
> - **Review similar questions.** Community members have suggested similar questions that may solve the problem. Do any of these answer
>   your question?
> - **Select the suggestions that answer your question.** Your question will be associated with these links so future visitors can easily find
>   the answer. Your question will be marked as a duplicate and become
>   visible to the public again.

As an experienced user of the site, I know how closing works and didn't find this email notification problematic. Specifically, I barely looked at it because I saw it after I already knew the question was closed. But, new users might find it rather confusing.

It starts by stating that your question is closed.

But then the *what should I next* section is a bit ambiguous. It goes on to saying *"Review similar questions"* and *"Select the suggestions that answer your question"* which is not possible anymore.

As evident by the linked Meta above, this can be confusing, especially to new users (who are the ones that get their questions closed more than others...).

I think the phrasing should be changed and my official suggestion is to remove the *what should I do next* section completely. The question is closed and there are links for the OP to look for their answer. The only necessary follow-up is ***What if these suggestions don’t answer my question?*** which is the following section.

---

I only got one question closed, here on Meta, and don't know if this is even a problem over at Main or any other SE sites. If someone is familiar with the issue, please suggest a better place for posting this.

---

Posting the full mail as an image for context and reference:

<sup>* The <kbd>Review similar questions</kbd> button simply links to the closed question itself</sup>

[image]

Comment: I think it makes sense. If your question is closed as a duplicate, you should review both the suggested questions and other related questions.

Comment: The phrasing of *__Select__ the suggestions that answer your question* give a feeling that you can do something, as demonstrated in the previous meta I linked where the user was confused. My point is that this whole section is useless and should just be What if these suggestions don’t answer my question?

Comment: The "Select..." part is not the only part that's problematic. It goes on to say _"Your question will be associated with these links"_ (I read "these links" to mean "the ones you selected") - Umm, no it won't. It already is! My guess is that some of this text gets sent to users when their question gets one or more close votes/flags but it's not yet closed. And it looks like they used the same text for the email that gets sent after the question is closed.

Comment: I think that can be solved with some rewording. E.g. See if any of the suggestions answer your question and Your question has been marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agreed, the copy on Closed As Duplicate emails was a little unclear.  We shipped an update last week and addressed in this meta post:

[Wrong instructions in email about duplicate question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375597/209031)

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be changed to this:

> **This question was marked as a duplicate**. It is closed and not accepting answers.
>
> **Question:**
>
> **Feedback:** This may be a duplicate question. Community members have suggested similar questions that may solve the problem. Review these to see if the question is a duplicate.
>
> [...]
>
> **What should I do next?**
>
> - **Review similar questions**. Community members have suggested similar questions that may solve the problem. Do any of these answer your question?
> - **Take a look at the suggestions to see if they answer your question**. Your question is associated with these links so future visitors can easily find the answer.

The reason I think it should stay as "This may be a duplication question" is that not every question closed as a duplicate actually IS a duplicate. Sometimes people get it wrong. Everything else looks okay to me.